# Unable to mount secondary HDD on CentOS 6.7 (Must specify file system?)

Tags: ubuntu, centos, mount, hard-disk, loop-device

I have a secondary HDD that worked fine in Ubuntu 13.04. I had mounted in to `/media/user/<some UUID>/`. I could read and write files without problem. My Ubuntu installation was on a primary SSD.

I was forced to install CentOS 6.7 due to my new company policy. Now when I try to mount the drive I have issues.

`sudo fdisk -l`

yields

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00095739

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
```

The `sudo mount -t autofs -o loop,offset=32256 /dev/sdb /secondary_hdd/`
says

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so`
```

Then
`sudo file -Ls /dev/sdb` yields

```
/dev/sdb: x86 boot sector, code offset 0xb8
```

And
 `dmesg` yields

```
sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/931 GiB)
sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
 sdb:
sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk`
```

I did not format the secondary disk so not sure what is wrong.

**Update:**
I tried `sudo mount /dev/sdb /secondary_hdd` but it does not work (must specify file system).

Comment: It looks like you don't have any partitions there. In any case, your mount command is wrong. What do you get for `sudo mount /dev/sdb /secondary_hdd/`? Why are you using `loop`? And why `autofs`? What is supposed to be there?

Comment: @terdon Thanks for helping me. I tried the above command `sudo mount /dev/sdb /secondary_hdd/` before I posted the question and I get `mount: you must specify the filesystem type`. Hence I tried the loop method.

Comment: loop won't help you there, the main issue is that it looks like your drive has no partitions. You seem to have deleted them during your centos installation.

Comment: I am pretty sure I did not delete anything on that drive. Is there a way to recover data before I can reformat the HDD? If not on Linux may be on Windows/Mac?